# how to calculate weighted mutual information

Tags: information-theory

I would like to ask how to calculate weighted mutual information?

Absolute mutual information is $H(A)+H(B)-H(A,B)$.

In practice:

$$H(A) = 0.3$$
$$H(B) = 1$$
$$H(A,B) = 1.25$$

Mutual information is = $0.05$
How about weighted?

And perhaps how could we explain weighted mutual information?

Comment: Do you have a definition of "weighted mutual information" ? Are you asking for it ?

Comment: @leonbloy I apologize for very late reply. I am looking for some equation, where I could find out percentage or log return of mutual information.

Comment: @leonbloy To calculate how much percentage mutual information consist of common space.